# add php code to html files in directories

Tags: text-editor

I need to add a php code block to some html files (html files are been procesed by php), Lets say I have this line of code:

```
<?php echo "hello world"; ?>
```

And I want to add that block to all .html files just before the closing "body" tag in the public_html folder of several domains:

```
/home/domainA/public_html
/home/domainB/public_html
/home/domainC/public_html
```

What's the best approach?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Do you have access to a bash shell and tools like `sed`?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: So you're asking how to add a line do a large number of text files? That doesn't actually have anything to do with PHP.

Comment: @thejh Linux, and yes, I have access to sed or any other thing

Comment: @sLaks where if it can be done any other way ok, i'm not very skillful with linux or shell stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `find` command to locate all `.html` files in the specified directories, then use `sed` to manipulate the files automatically. **Make sure to create a backup before trying something like this, there's a reason why this is called [search-and-destroy](http://catb.org/jargon/html/S/search-and-destroy-mode.html)!**

```
find /home/domainA/public_html  /home/domainB/public_html \
     /home/domainC/public_html  -name '*.html'            \
     -exec sed -i 's|</body>|<?php echo "hello world"; ?>|' '{}' ';'
```

Comment: This works perfectly, just one thing: can I put the content I want to add in a file and pass it to the sed command?  This is because my block code is much more larger and complex than echo "hello world" and if I try to do it the way you put it it give me a syntax error near unexpected token '|'

Comment: @Pavel How about putting your big block of code into a seperate file? You could then insert `<?php include "<path to file>"; ?>` into the html pages. That's probably also a good idea if you ever want to change that block – that way, you won't have to change it in all those files again.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way. . .

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>
        <?php echo "hello world" ?>
     </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is to put the block into a partial and the call it in your main file. For example:

```
//partial.phtml
<?php echo "hello world"; ?>

//main.phtml
<body>
<?php
echo $this->partial('partial.phtml');
?>
</body>
```

Calling to a partial will depend on the PHP framework you are using. Hope this helps!